# How to Pull a Column Value based on Logic Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
TotalCost Year Type
$100      2005 Honda
$200      2006 Toyota
$300      2007 Honda
$100      2005 Mazda
$400      2006 Honda
$300      2007 Honda
```

I would like to create a new column that pulls the nest years TotalCost value. So for example, in the first row, the code would see a `2005` `Honda`. It would then search the rest of the data frame for `2006` `Honda` and return the `2006` `Honda` `TotalCost` as a new column called `NextYearCost` on the same row where `2005` `Honda` is found.

Next, the code would go to the second row of the data frame. It would see that it is a `2006` `Toyota`. The code would then search the data frame for `2007` and `Toyota`. However, because there is no `2007` `Toyota` the data frame would return `NA` in the `NextYearCost` column. The code would do this for each row in the dataframe.

Desired dataframe with new column, `NextYearCost`:

```
TotalCost Year Type    NextYearCost
$100      2005 Honda   $200
$200      2006 Toyota  NA
$300      2007 Honda   NA
$100      2005 Mazda   $400
$400      2006 Mazda   NA
$300      2007 Honda   NA
```

Maybe it's something like:

```
df.loc[(df['column_name'] == some_value) & df['other_column'].isin(some_values)]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution but merging on your category and year+1 would work. (also may need a check for duplicates, eg I used your original data that had two entries for Honda 2007 so the merge adds a duplicate row of data)

```
#import
import pandas as pd
#data
df = pd.DataFrame({'TotalCost': [100, 200, 300, 100, 400, 300], 'Year':[2005, 2006, 2007, 2005, 2006, 2007], 'Type': ['Honda', 'Toyota', 'Honda', 'Mazda', 'Honda', 'Honda']})
df
Out: 
   TotalCost    Type  Year
0        100   Honda  2005
1        200  Toyota  2006
2        300   Honda  2007
3        100   Mazda  2005
4        400   Honda  2006
5        300   Honda  2007
df['next_year'] = df['Year'] + 1
df
Out: 
   TotalCost    Type  Year  next_year
0        100   Honda  2005       2006
1        200  Toyota  2006       2007
2        300   Honda  2007       2008
3        100   Mazda  2005       2006
4        400   Honda  2006       2007
5        300   Honda  2007       2008
df = pd.merge(df, df, how='left', left_on=['next_year', 'Type'], right_on=['Year', 'Type'])
df
Out: 
   TotalCost_x    Type  Year_x  next_year_x  TotalCost_y  Year_y  next_year_y
0          100   Honda    2005         2006        400.0  2006.0       2007.0
1          200  Toyota    2006         2007          NaN     NaN          NaN
2          300   Honda    2007         2008          NaN     NaN          NaN
3          100   Mazda    2005         2006          NaN     NaN          NaN
4          400   Honda    2006         2007        300.0  2007.0       2008.0
5          400   Honda    2006         2007        300.0  2007.0       2008.0
6          300   Honda    2007         2008          NaN     NaN          NaN
```

Then if you so desire you can drop some columns and cleanup the resulting table:

```
df.drop(['Year_y', 'next_year_y', 'next_year_x'], inplace=True, axis=1)
df.rename(columns={'TotalCost_x':'TotalCost', 'Year_x': 'Year', 'TotalCost_y': 'NextYearCost'}, inplace=True)
df
Out: 
   TotalCost    Type  Year  NextYearCost
0        100   Honda  2005         400.0
1        200  Toyota  2006           NaN
2        300   Honda  2007           NaN
3        100   Mazda  2005           NaN
4        400   Honda  2006         300.0
5        400   Honda  2006         300.0
6        300   Honda  2007           NaN
```

Comment: This works great. The actual dataframe I was using had many more columns in the dataframe, so I filtered one of the dataframes down with 
`df = pd.merge(df[['next_year', 'Type', 'TotalCost']], df, how='left', left_on=['next_year', 'Type'], right_on=['Year', 'Type'])`